# Why $\frac{(-i)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{x^2+p^2} e^{ipx} H_n(p) e^{-p^2/2} dp \approx \sqrt{2n+1} H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, hermite-polynomials

Why the below holds for $n\geq 1$?
$$\frac{(-i)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{x^2+p^2} e^{ipx} H_n(p) e^{-p^2/2} dp \approx \sqrt{2n+1} H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}.$$

The Hermite polynomial is defined as
$$H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2}.$$

I have a numerical evidence that LHS and RHS are very similar for $n\geq 1$. For $n=0,\ldots, 4$, I computed the both sides numerically, and obtained the following:

[image]

The blue line is LHS, and the orange line is RHS. They agree quite well, but there is a small difference. Indeed, at $x=0$, we can compute the both sides analytically, and there was some (~10%) discrepancy. Still, why there are approximately equal is a mystery.

Comment: How could some one find this question on the net regarding to the tile? Regards!

Comment: I don't think there is perfect agreement for the $n\geq 1$ terms as you can see via the graphs.

Comment: @BenjaminWang That could be the numerical error. Also, I have another reason that the Hermite function is expected to be an eigenfunction for the "integral kernel". (See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365667/what-is-int-mathbb-r2-sqrt-fracxy22p2-eipx-y-e-y2-2h )

Comment: Without the square roots (i.e. with $(x^2+p^2)^1$ and $(2n+1)^1$ instead) the equation would be correct (follows from the Hermite functions being eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform and their differential equation). With them, I don't think the statement is true. For even $n$ you can plug in $x = 0$ to see that there is a difference (not just numerically: Mathematica can do the symbolic integration). It could be interesting to quantify the discrepancy though, since it seems to become very small for large $n$.

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial Thanks for your very interesting comment. I found out that there is some (~10%) discrepancy of LHS and RHS at $x=0$. Yet, the approximate equality is still a mystery. I edited my question.

Comment: Does the approximation get better if $n$ is large or $x$ is large or both?

Comment: @Gary The approximation gets better if $n$ is large.